# Installed NodeJS and suddenly my python DLL is missing

Tags: python, node.js, dll

So yesterday I installed NodeJS for a college project. On the installer, I chose the full install (the installer said some libraries need C/C++ dependecies or something like that). Anyway, midway through the install there was an error, but I was able to use NodeJS with no problems. However, today I tried to execute a Python file and it told me that the python39.dll file was missing. Upon checking, I found this: [image: Python folder] on the python main folder. Should I just reinstall Python altogether or is there a way to replenish just this missing DLL? And what could have caused this so I'm more aware in the future? Thanks for your time!

Comment: "Upon checking, I found this" Okay, so what exactly do you think should be included here that isn't? Also, what exactly leads you to believe that the node.js installation is responsible for this? Also, you need to show the [full error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) as well as exactly how you attempted to run the Python file, for us to be able to tell you anything useful.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I meant that the DLL wasn't on the python main folder. I believe it was the node installation because it was the only thing that changed in my PC. I tried rebooting it to no end. Here's the full error: http://prntscr.com/11jou0g Sorry for not doing it all in the first place

Comment: "I meant that the DLL wasn't on the python main folder" **what DLL?** The screenshot shows us what **is** there, not what **isn't**.

Comment: Can you run *any* python script? Can you run `py` by itself and get an interpreter prompt?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I meant the "python39.dll" that the error keeps talking about. And no, I can't run any python script, everything I try raises the same error. Running a py script on vscode just prints out the python.exe location followed by the script location

Comment: "Running a py script on vscode", no, I mean, instead of typing `py server.py`, just type `py`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know, as I said, everything I try raises the same error. Tried running just py on cmd and executing the python.exe to no avail

Comment: I would reinstall Python, yeah. You might also have better luck on https://superuser.com.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hey, sorry for the late reply, but do you know of a way to keep all of my libraries before I reinstall since I can't use "pip freeze > reqs.txt"? Anyway, thanks for the patience and for the help!